# SSO not working for external users

Tags: c#, azure, single-sign-on

I have an azure account who is an external user.

I developed a web application with Owin Authentication which uses Single Sign-On with Azure Active Directory.

**Success case:**

1.Login with the user id in Online Azure(manage.windowsazure.com).

2.Open my application. Login with Azure ADFS will just log in the user using SSO.

3.Log out of the Online Azure

**Failure case:**

1.Open my application. Login with Azure ADFS will ask for Azure credentials. I entered the credentials and the login is success.

2.Now open the manage.windowsazure.com.It should be automatically log in. But it is getting the wrong user id and failed to login.

3.The #EXT is appends in the User ID and shows its not a valid email id. How to prevent this ?

[Error message when tries to login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev0UE.png)

Note: Everything works fine for normal azure user.

Thanks in advance.